# Can I compare items from two separate arrays?

Tags: java, select, radio-button

Can I compare the the position of an item in an array to the position of a specific value in another array ? For example, if given this code `"What animals are in this picture?", "image_id": 2394390, "candidates": ["Bear.", "Giraffe.", "Cow.", "Dogs."], "candidate_ids": [465266, 465267, 465265, -1], "id": 671936}` can I compare the list and come to the conclusion that dogs corresponds to -1 ? I want to manipulate it further, but this is the beginning step

Comment: Can you provide more information or the code of your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things here that I want to address:

It looks like you are trying to use a combination of jQuery and Javascript. Are you trying to accomplish this using straight Javascript, or can you use jQuery? Also can you provide some information on what your HTML might look like? How you accomplish this task is entirely dependent on what your HTML looks like. As of right now, there are no radio buttons to click so I can't help. I will edit my answer once you provide a little more information.

Also, Java and Javascript are 2 very different things. This post is tagged as Java.. might want to fix that.

Comment: In other words: Can I compare the the position of an item in an array to the position of a specific value in another array ? For example, if given this code "What animals are in this picture?", "image_id": 2394390, "candidates": ["Bear.", "Giraffe.", "Cow.", "Dogs."], "candidate_ids": [465266, 465267, 465265, -1], "id": 671936} can I compare the list and come to the conclusion that dogs corresponds to -1 ? I want to manipulate it further, but this is the beginning step.